# Simplification of probability expression

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Let $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ be probabilities such that $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1$, and let $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ be arbitrary constants.

Can the following expression be written in terms of $p_1$ and constants alone?

$$\frac{c_2}{c_1}p_2 + \frac{c_3}{c_1}p_3$$

Comment: It' impossible. Imagine you decrease $p_2$ by the amount you increase $p_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 1:

$$\frac{c_2}{c_1}p_2 + \frac{c_3}{c_1}p_3$$

$$= \frac{c_2}{c_1}(1-p_1-p_3) + \frac{c_3}{c_1}p_3$$

$$= \frac{c_2}{c_1}(1-p_1)+\frac{c_2}{c_1}(-p_3) + \frac{c_3}{c_1}p_3$$

$$= \frac{c_2}{c_1}(1-p_1)+\frac{-c_2}{c_1}(p_3) + \frac{c_3}{c_1}p_3$$

$$= \frac{c_2}{c_1}(1-p_1)+\frac{c_3-c_2}{c_1}(p_3)$$

Try 2:

$$\frac{c_2}{c_1}p_2 + \frac{c_3}{c_1}p_3$$

$$= \frac{c_2}{c_1}p_2 + \frac{c_3}{c_1}(1-p_1-p_2)$$

$$= \frac{c_3}{c_1}(1-p_1)+\frac{c_2-c_3}{c_1}(p_2)$$

It apperars no.

Sufficient conditions:

1. $$c_2=c_3$$
2. $$p_2=0$$
3. $$p_3=0$$